# How can I set a custom Content-Type to jax-rs client?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, content-type

I am running some JAX-RS resources declared like this:

```
public interface MyEntityServiceV2 {
    @PUT
    @Consumes({"application/myentity-v2+json"})
    @Produces({"application/myentity-v2+json"})
    @Path("/{uuid:[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}}")
    Response putMyEntity(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid, MyEntityDto myEntity);
}
```

Now I want to test them using the Jersey-Client (or any other client if it helps to fix my issue):

```
MyEntityDto dto = new MyEntityDto();
Entity<MyEntityDto> entity = Entity.entity(dto, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:7001/path/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request("application/myentity-v2+json");
builder.header("Content-Type", "application/myentity-v2+json");
Response response = builder.put(entity);
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The request always contains a content type of application/json. And this does not match the interface on the server.

As an alternative I can create the entity with my custom MediaType which also leads to an error because it can’t find the MessageBodyWriter for that type.

Oh and I can’t change the service declaration.

What do you think is the best way to test this resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an entity with your custom MediaType, and then register a custom MessageBodyWriter with your Client. It could be as simple as extending an existing MessageBodyWrite to return `true` when `isWritable` is called, or you may have to implement the `writeTo` method.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Think that is not a too bad solution.